# JVM, байт код, компилятор

Tags: java

Никак не могу разобраться и путаюсь просто.

> Компилятор Java не компилирует все классы в одну программу из машинных
>   кодов. Вместо этого он компилирует каждый класс по отдельности и не в
>   машинные коды, а в специальный промежуточный код (байт-код).
>   Компиляция в машинный код выполняется при запуске программы.

— А кто же компилирует программу в машинный код при ее запуске?

—

> Есть специальная программа под названием JVM (Java Virtual Machine) –
>   Виртуальная Машина Java. Именно ее запускают первой, когда нужно
>   запустить программу, состоящую из байт-кода. А уже JVM перед
>   выполнением нужной программы компилирует ту в машинный код.

Правильно ли я понял, мы написали код потом этот из этого кода компилятор делает байт-код, а потом JVM из этого байт-кода делает машинный код и потом что? Программа запускается или что? И вообще правильно ли я описал поэтапность всего этого? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: jvm это программа, она запускается сама, затем запускает Вашу программу примерно как Вы и описали.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Извините, вы бы не могли пошагово расписать для меня новичка :) чтобы я уже наконец-таки понял :)

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AnRKrnbiVzU

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Если вкратце описать это правильно: Вы пишите код на языке Java, компилятор компилирует его в byte-code и JVM уже запускает этот байт код?

Comment: похоже что Вы все верно поняли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> А кто же компилирует программу в машинный код при ее запуске?

В общем случае никто, JVM [интерпретирует](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) байткод. Но в частности виртуальная машина HotSpot использует [JIT-компилятор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) для компиляции байткода в машинный код.

> Правильно ли я понял, мы написали код потом этот из этого кода
>   компилятор делает байт-код, а потом JVM из этого байт-кода делает
>   машинный код и потом что? Программа запускается или что?

[Виртуальная машина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) - загружает байткод из class-файлов и выполняет их на, грубо говоря, виртуальном процессоре.

Comment: Если вкратце описать это правильно: Вы пишите код на языке Java, компилятор компилирует его в byte-code и JVM уже запускает этот байт код?

Comment: @MikeMclaren д​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌а.

Comment: Спасибо большое!